# Insert a sequence and SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert, sequence

I'm trying to insert into a table, where the ID is the next in a sequence, and some of the other values are pulled from a table. I know that this won't work:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS(order_id, foo1, foo2, foo3
VALUES(SEQUENCE_ORDERS.nextval,(SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3
                                FROM bar
                                WHERE X = Y))
```

I just tried, and it I get a "not enough values" error.

I wanted to know what the correct syntax was to get this to work. I'm using PLSQL in an Oracle DB (part of a procedure I'm writing).

I know that the select should not be inside the VALUES() but how do I also add the sequence? The only option I can think of would be a trigger on the insert, but I'd rather not have to do that.

EDIT: thank you all, just as I figured it out, everyone posted. Didn't know it was ok to have the sequence in the select.

Comment: Sometimes I just need to type out what problem I'm having then all of a sudden it comes to me. Thanks to those answered!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS(order_id, foo1, foo2, foo3)
SELECT SEQUENCE_ORDERS.nextval,foo1, foo2, foo3
                                FROM bar
                                WHERE X = Y
```

Comment: @DCookie - LOL, :) only beat you by 11 secs

Comment: @DCookie: Be nice now -- dcp's a *thief!* =)

Comment: +1, i'll defer to your lightning typing skills, plus you fixed the syntax error too

Comment: @Thanks guys, you're cracking me up today ;).

Comment: As the poster, I declare dcp is the victor here.

Comment: @Null, please remember to "accept" @DCP's answer and don't forget to tip your waitress.

Comment: @Cos, I know but I have to wait a few minutes before I can. Will do it asap, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS(order_id, foo1, foo2, foo3
SELECT SEQUENCE_ORDERS.nextval, foo1, foo2, foo3
                                FROM bar
                                WHERE X = Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the SEQUENCE over to the SELECT statement.